# pdf2swf not working with crontab

Tags: cron, pdf2swf

I have a python program (queue.py) that convert PDF files to SWF files. It uses pdf2swf tool to achieve that. Now my problem is when I start this program manually by "python queue.py", it works fine. But the same program when I started using crontab.

Result shows

pdf2swf -o "/var/www/code_repository/younus/staff/../staffdocs/AIK/doc/248515566214636_IMPROVEMENT_IN_ELECTRIC_LIGHTS.swf" "/var/www/code_repository/younus/staff/../staffdocs/AIK/doc/248515566214636_IMPROVEMENT_IN_ELECTRIC_LIGHTS.pdf">/dev/zero

### "sh: pdf2swf: not found"

Inside crontab -e

### * * * * * python /home/francis/myjobs/queue.py

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the binary in your `PATH`, or specify an explicit path name.  You may also need to set up the Python library path etc to match the environment of your interactive shell.